# Не работает слушатель во Fragment

Tags: java, android

У меня есть main класс в нем есть FrameLayout в который закидывается фрагмент. Ниже привожу код фрагмента

```
public class Groups extends Fragment implements GroupAdapter.MyOnItemClickListener{
public static final String TAG = "Fragment Groups";
interfaces.Groups groups;
RecyclerView GroupsList;
GroupAdapter adapter;



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group,container,false);

    SharedPreferences shf = view.getContext().getSharedPreferences("User", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String idUser = shf.getString("UserId", "");


    GroupsList = view.findViewById(R.id.ListGroup);
    ArrayList<GroupModel> models = new ArrayList<>();




    models.add(new GroupModel("fd", "null", 7, 14, 1, "32", "32"));


    RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    GroupsList.setLayoutManager(manager);
    GroupsList.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onTouchEvent: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    });
    adapter = new GroupAdapter(view.getContext(), models);
    GroupsList.setAdapter(adapter);
    GroupsList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    return view;
}


@Override
public void ClickedItem(View view, int position) {
    Log.i(TAG, "ClickedItem: ");
}
```

И что бы я не делал, куда бы я не ставил слушатели(в коде далее вы увидите куда я их только не запихивал), ничего не помогает..может быть у кого идеи найдуться при обычном активити это работает на ура

Вот код адаптера для RecyclerView.

```
public class GroupAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GroupAdapter.MyHolder>{

public interface MyOnItemClickListener
{
    void ClickedItem(View view,int position);
}

private MyOnItemClickListener myListener;
Context context;
ArrayList<GroupModel> models;
public GroupAdapter(Context ctxt,ArrayList<GroupModel> models)
{

    this.models = models;
    context = ctxt;
}



@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.group_item,parent,false);
    MyHolder hold = new MyHolder(view);
    return hold;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.nameGroup.setText(models.get(position).getChatName());
    holder.textGroup.setText(models.get(position).getTextMsg());
    holder.dateTime.setText(models.get(position).getDateMsg());
    RequestCreator pic = Picasso.get()
            .load(models.get(position).getProfImage());
          pic.into(holder.image);
    holder.cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("ds", "onClick: ");
        }
    });

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("dsds", "onClick: ");
            myListener.ClickedItem(v,position);
        }
    });
    holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("hfg", "onClick: ");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return models.size();
}


public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView nameGroup,textGroup,dateTime;
    ImageView image;
    LinearLayout layout;
    CardView cv;
    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lay_group);
        nameGroup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameGroup);
        textGroup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textGroup);
        dateTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateTimeGroup);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.avaGroup);
        cv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardGroup);



    }

}
```

---

Вот Group

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/ListGroup"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Вот Group_item

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay_group"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/avaGroup"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nameGroup"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:text="Бла бла"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:id="@+id/textGroup"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="bottom"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:gravity="right|bottom"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:id="@+id/dateTimeGroup"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Тут тоже вроде ничего нет

Comment: Скорее всего тач перехвачен слушателем из адаптера. Попробуйте убрать все слушатели нажатий из `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: Попробовал, не работает, но дело в том что даже самого нажатия не происходит..как будто бы на нем ниет вообще события.

Comment: Покажите разметку холдера - может там что-то есть

Comment: Да, в разметке вроде ничего нет. Если без слушателей в холжере тоже не работает, то, возможно, вам просто не нужен внешний слушатель? Какую задачу вы хотите с его помощью решить? Если просто получить событие клика по ячейке, то оно у вас уже сделано это в холдере.

Comment: Мне нужно что бы я смог получить данные от вью посредством клика на нено, но ни внешний слушатель( внутри фрагмента) ни внутренний который бы был в адаптере никаких результатов не дает..логов нет..я не зря прислал кучу слушателей что бы было видно что я все испробывал..даже паттерн наблюдателя. но он не дает..такое ощущение будто бы слушателя вообще и нет ( как например в простом активити если убрать слушател в onBindViewHolder).. я пробовал в качестве контекста использовать getActivity и  getContext  и view.getContext -- ничего не помогает

Comment: Слушатель в холдере точно должен работать. Если в логи не выводит - где-то ошибка. Где - из кода не видно. Попробуйте дебаггером пройтись и посмотреть заходит ли исполнение в слушатель в холдере.

Comment: Попробовал поставить брекпоинты на точках установки слушателей и непостредственно в слушателях( на логах)) ..на точках установки слушателей бреки останавливаются, а вот внутрь не забегают при формировании списка( что логично ведь мы на них не нажимаем) но после формирования списка при нажатии.. брекпоинты не останавливают свидетельствуя о том что нажатия как бы не было...просто не понятно ем может быть вызвана данная ошибка

Comment: Что-то, видимо, перехватывает клик. Вы ведь пробуете сейчас в холдере без внешнего слушателя тача? Если ничего не работает - попробуйте с нуля ещё раз написать весь экран - должно заработать, т.к. в коде всё верно, возможно проблема где-то в непоказанном вами коде)

Comment: Да я по всякому пробовал.. и просто на view  слушатель повесить и чисто в холдере в Onbind  и на CreateHolder-е..да тут писать-то нечего..3 строчки)) в этом и непонятка..почему слушатель не срабатывает...может RrameLayout  как-то может повлиять на это? или CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: Контейнеры влиять не должны... Может у вас InstantRun сбоит? Он у вас отключен? В любом случае, раз у вас не работает - перепишите с нуля. Как заработает - построчно сравнивайте и ищите в чём проблема)